# react native : customize flatlist to timeline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using react-native flatlist to create a `timeline` for my project.

What I want to do is to see check if `flatlist data` has same `date` and if so, `place flat list`date`in one row`. Like this:

[image]

My flatlist data will look like this:

```
const list = [
  {
    name: 'Sunny',
    avatar_url: '../Components/Assets/pic1.png',
    time:'Monday 16',
  },
  {
    name: 'Kaya',
    avatar_url: '../Components/Assets/pic2.png',
    time:'Monday 16',
  },
  {
    name: 'Kiki',
    avatar_url: '../Components/Assets/pic3.png',
    time:'Tuesday 21',
  },
 ...
]
```

If the `time data` in flat list is the same, is there a way I can `merge data` and just show it once like the photo? Also, custom style the borders lines as well.

Any advise or comments would be really helpful thanks in advance! :)

**Editied**

@vitosorriso 
This is my `renderItem code`

```
renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
  return (
    <ListItem
      attachToPreviousItem={index > 0 && list[index].time === list[index - 1].time ? true : false}
      containerStyle={styles.cardStyle}
      title={<View><Text>{item.name}</Text></View>}
      subtitle={<View>
          <Text style={{fontSize:16}}>{item.time}</Text>
          </View>}
     />
        </View>
      }
    />
  )
}
```

My Flat list:

```
<FlatList
                 keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
                 data={list}
                 renderItem={this.renderItem}
```

**Edited**

@Joseph

My render method:

```
  styleDate = () => {
    Object.keys(listObj).map(time => {
     <Text>{ time }</Text>
     listObj[time].map( data => {
        return (
          <ComponentWithImage data={ data }/>
        )
     })
   })
}
```

My Flatlist:

```
  <FlatList
                 data={listObj}
                 renderItem={this.styleDate}
               />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be this:

1. Define a prop-based style for the single item (since the item will have to hide the date and have set vertical margins/padding to 0, you can pass this prop set to `true` if you have to hide the date and margins/padding, and `false` if it is a normal item), i will call this prop `attachToPreviousItem`
2. Edit your flatlist's `renderItem` function like this:

```js
renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
  return (
    <Item
      attachToPreviousItem={index > 0 && list[index].time === list[index - 1].time ? true : false}
      // other props here
    />
  )
}
```

With this, you can check in your `list` array if the actual item has the same time of the previous item, and give to it a different style based on this condition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I see no changes. Would this work in react-native? I edited my code could you please check?

Answer (score 1):

making a hash based on date will be a good, for Eg:

your List

```
const list = [
  {
    name: 'Sunny',
    avatar_url: '../Components/Assets/pic1.png',
    time:'Monday 16',
  },
  {
    name: 'Kaya',
    avatar_url: '../Components/Assets/pic2.png',
    time:'Monday 16',
  },
  {
    name: 'Kiki',
    avatar_url: '../Components/Assets/pic3.png',
    time:'Tuesday 21',
  },
 ...
]
```

convert this to object

```
listObj = {
    "Monday 16": [ {
        name: 'Sunny',
        avatar_url: '../Components/Assets/pic1.png',
        time:'Monday 16',
      }, {
        name: 'Kaya',
        avatar_url: '../Components/Assets/pic2.png',
        time:'Monday 16',
      }  ],
     "Tuesday 21": [{
       name: 'Kiki',
       avatar_url: '../Components/Assets/pic3.png',
       time:'Tuesday 21',
    }]
  }


loop over the listObj

Object.keys(listObj).map(time => {
  return (
   <span>{ time } </span> // date
   listObj[time].map( data => {
      return (
        <ComponentWithImage data={ data }/>
      )
   })
  )
})
```

just an idea
Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer it really helps! But explain your last code `listobj[time]` and `<ComponentWithImage data={ data }/>`

Comment: @kirimilist 1. listObj is the object having time as a key and value as the array of object having same time, its just a mapping of time and related objects by time            2. ComponentWithImage is a functional component returning the image icon

Comment: thanks for the explanation. But still I am having trouble applying this to my flatlist. What would my flatlist structure be?

Comment: @kirimi to be more specific according to me your FlatList Component should be like this (just a thought on this) <FlatList data= { listObj } /> and FlatList Component should be like this render() {  Object.keys(listObj).map(time => {
  return (
   <span>{ time } </span> // date
   listObj[time].map( data => {
      return (
        <ComponentWithImage data={ data }/> // function component returning image or use can you image also here
      )
   })
  )
})  }

Comment: I think you answer is right. But I am still confused maybe because I am using react-native not react. I edited my code could you take a look?